# How to find bytes_in in Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I am using this module https://github.com/Lax/ngx_http_accounting_module for accounting nginx request count and byte out

I can see bytes_out is used in code and is working fine .

code snippet:
ngx_http_accounting_handler(ngx_http_request_t *r){
..
stats->bytes_out += r->connection->sent;
}

But how to calculate bytes_in? any clue? I checked ngx_http_request_s & ngx_connection_s which has 'sent' data but not the receive data. Any suggestion would be really helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use r->request_length, much like it's done in nginx core for the [$request_length](http://nginx.org/r/log_format) log module variable.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated `ngx_http_accounting_module`, adding `bytes_in support`.

The original version(v0.1) of `ngx_http_accounting_module` didn't implement `bytes_in`.

In v0.2, this value is added to the stats variable.

```
     stats->nr_requests += 1;
+    stats->bytes_in += r->request_length;
     stats->bytes_out += r->connection->sent;
```

Output format is changed as following code, adding `bytes_in:` to the output buffer.

```
-    sprintf(output_buffer, "pid:%i|from:%ld|to:%ld|accounting_id:%s|requests:%ld|bytes_out:%ld",
+    sprintf(output_buffer, "pid:%i|from:%ld|to:%ld|accounting_id:%s|requests:%ld|bytes_in:%ld|bytes_out:%ld",
                 ngx_getpid(),
                 ngx_http_accounting_old_time,
                 ngx_http_accounting_new_time,
                 name,
                 stats->nr_requests,
+                stats->bytes_in,
                 stats->bytes_out
             );
```

For more detail, see here: https://github.com/Lax/ngx_http_accounting_module/tree/v0.2 .

Thanks Maxim Dounin!